# Redirect on item save

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, custom-form

I have a list that I want to redirect the users back to a page I found the below jscrpit but I must be doing something wrong. I am open to any suggestions on doing it different as well.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var button = $(“input[id$=SaveItem]”);
// change redirection behavior
button.removeAttr(“onclick”);
button.click(function() {
var elementName = $(this).attr(“name”);
var aspForm = document.forms[‘aspnetForm’];
var oldUrl = aspForm.action;
var SourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue(“Source”, true, oldUrl );
var newUrl = oldUrl .replace(SourceValue , “/SitePages/testing.aspx”);
if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, “”, true, “”, newUrl , false, true));
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently asked the same question and got the below answer:

> 1.) Click add a new item in your list. Now the NewForm.aspx Form opens up.
>
> 2.) Edit this page and add a Script Editor or CEWP.
>
> 3.) Now use the Presave function (code written under this function executes when the 'save' button is clicked). You can add some code to
>   the script editor or CEWP.
>
> Note: You need to add reference for Jquery in the code, on the top.
>
> See code below for reference:
>
> Code starts here

```
 function PreSaveAction() {

 var url = "Paste Thank you Page Url here";

 window.location.href = url;

 }
```

> Code Ends here

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/192739/57040

And I commented this for further information:

> Thank you! This worked perfectly. I will say for anyone that might be
>   searching how to do this that I implemented this by adding a CEWP,
>   edited the HTML on it to include `<script src="<path to .js file in Site Assets"></script>`, then created the JavaScript file in SPD and
>   saved it to Site Assets. This was the most straightforward and easiest
>   method I've found to use so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with SharePoint 2010 try to use the solution of rolemartyr-x . but I am sure your above code is not working with SharePoint 2013 , and you will get this error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined`

To can do that at SharePoint 2013 as a workaround

- Open your all items page and set this code
- Add Script Editor.
- Add the following code.

> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script>
>
> $( document ).ready(function() {
>
> document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").removeAttribute("onclick");
>
>
> document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").href="http://epm/workflow/Lists/Shoe%20Models/NewForm.aspx?Source=add your custom page url"; 
> });
>
> </script>
> ```

**Note :** At `document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").href=` put your link to `NewForm` page before `Source Query String` and after it add your Custom Page URL that you want to go back.